# Migration of SQL Server stored procedures to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migrate

I have a question: what is the best practice for migrating SQL Server stored procedures to Oracle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Best* is such a fun word.

But.

Oracle SQL Developer has built in translators, including one for SQL Server.

If you capture your data model using the Migration Projects feature, it will take your T-SQL procedures and convert/translate them to their PL/SQL equivalents.

Each translation will need to be verified/approved/tested, of course.

We see somewhere between 60-90% translation success rates, that is, translated procedures being 'good, out-of-the-box.' Results will vary based on the nature of your code.

I talk about migrations, with Sybase ASE as an example, [in this whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/migrate-nonoracle-dbs-apps-to-12c-2379089.pdf). The SQL Server scenario would be pretty much the same.

We also have an ad-hoc translator, but it won't take into account your data model.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can attest from being involved in a large production legacy project, where substantial number of "automated" options had been evaluated - none of them worked, and almost nothing they did could even be used in the 'at least that' manner.

We wasted a lot of time trying to achieve automation, and then ended up converting everything by hand, which took much less when we involved a small team of coders, once they familiarized themselves with both syntax and optimisers.

Comment: Found the same thin when converting some several thousand line stored procedures (this was business logic that calculated commissions!!) to Oracle.  Scrapped the automated stuff from the Oracle translator and we re-wrote by hand.